# Difference between on('windows.alert()') and on('windows:alert') in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

```
cy.on('window:alert',(str)=>{
            expect(str).to.equal('Hello , share this practice page and share your knowledge');
        });
```

This was executing the assertion but,

```
cy.on('window.alert()',(str)=>{
            expect(str).to.equal('Hello , share this practice page and share your knowledge');
        });
```

But this was not executing the assertion. I am new to cypress and want to understand why and how these two are different?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no difference between them. The `cy.on()` method calls core `javascript` methods. Even if you do not add the `()` sign to the end of a function, the constructor method of the same method will be called, unless it takes a parameter inside the function.

Comment: But why did cypress did not assert in the case of second example?